# Set of partial limits of partial sums sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence converging to $0$, and let $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be its partial sums sequence, i.e., $S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$. Show that the set of subsequential limits of $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is the (possibly unbounded) interval $[\liminf S_k, \limsup S_k]$.

The intuitive idea of both questions is clear: since $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is eventually small, if $a<b$ are partial limits, then there is no way to get from $a$ to $b$ without going through every $c\in (a,b)$, since we add a "very small step" each time.

However, I couldn't find a formal proof which isn't very, very messy. Does anyone have a suggestion for proving this in a relatively "clean" way?

Comment: What is a “partial limit” of a sequence?

Comment: Is that a question or a clue? It is a limit of any subsequence

Comment: It’s a question, because it’s not a notion I’ve run into before. “Partial sum” sure, “subsequential limit” no problem. But “partial limit” I’ve never seen before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually found a somewhat concise solution.

**Lemma ("Mean value theorem" for sequences).** Let $\delta>0$. A sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ will be called *$\delta$-continuous*, if $|a_{n+1} - a_{n}|\leq \delta$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$.
So for such a sequence, every $n\leq m$ and every $\lambda$ between $a_n$ and $a_m$, there exists $n\leq k \leq m$ with $|a_k-\lambda|\leq \frac \delta 2$.

*Proof.* Assume the case $a_n < \lambda < a_m$. Take $k=\sup\{i\leq m \mid a_i\leq\lambda \}$, so $a_k \leq\lambda<a_{k+1}$. But $a_{k+1}-a_k < \delta$ and therefore at least one of $a_k,a_{k+1}$ are close enough to $\lambda$.$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

**Corollary.** If $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$ and $S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k a_k$, then the set of subsequential limits of $(S_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is $[\liminf S_k, \limsup S_k]$.

*Proof.* Let $a<b$ be subsequential limits of $(S_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, and let $a<c<b$. It will suffice to prove that $c$ is also a subsequential limit of $(S_k)_{k=1}^\infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be small enough so that $a+\varepsilon < c < b-\varepsilon$. Let $K\in \Bbb N$ and we should find $k>K$ with $|S_k - c| < \varepsilon$. For a large enough $N\in \Bbb N$ we have $|a_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Therefore, $(S_k)_{k=N}^\infty$ is $\varepsilon$-continuous. Take $k_1, k_2 > \max\{N,K\}$ with $|S_{k_1}-a| < \varepsilon$ and $|S_{k_2}-b|<\varepsilon$. Now, apply the lemma to obtain some $k$ between $k_1$ and $k_2$ with $|S_k - c| < \varepsilon$.$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$